# minimum PC hardware specification to reproduce 1080i at 30 fps

Tags: pc, processor, video-adapters

Due to budget constraints I constantly find myself several years behind "current" technology, when it comes to my PC hardware and operating systems. I do, however, make it a point to learn exactly what hardware is required to accomplish a given set of tasks.

Unfortunately, matching system specifications to a given task is often a game. I can't tell you how many times I've been told that I CAN'T accomplish things I regularly do with ease on one of my systems. Often people will speak authoritatively about the absolute need for hardware that is WAY over qualified, and equally over priced for my needs.

With this background I am asking for direct experience with the task I've outlined, to find out what critical specs and PC hardware (CPU type, clock speed, FSB speeds, number of cores, OS, Video card specs) I will need to accomplish one simple thing: Be able to live stream videos, play DVDs, and play various downloaded video/movie files, while driving my TV to its full 1920 x 1080 resolution, and at a reasonable frame rate ( which I assume should be at least 30fps). In addition to the actual specs, it will be a helpful addition to know HOW LONG AGO such specs became pretty common. I.e., if what I need became common place in 2010, that is a helpful reference point.

I probably will want a windows box, if only because I've been intimately acquainted with most MS OS's for many years. I'm also looking for used equipment, because I doubt these tasks really require the latest, greatest machine. Again... not looking for brand recommendations, but the system specifications needed to easilly perform the task.

Note: I have edited both the title and content of this post several times now both for brevity and clarity. For that reason, many comments no longer apply. Also, as the comment thread has already gotten too long, I ask that any further comments or answers at this point be limited to addressing the info I'm seeking.

Comment: [Raspberry Pi](https://www.raspberrypi.org/) is cheap, and can play Full HD video, with a few [caveats](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/1575/can-the-raspberry-pi-be-used-as-a-media-center). This will probably cost about [$85](http://www.howtogeek.com/163541/build-a-35-media-center-with-raspbmc-and-raspberry-pi-redux/), but can be as low as $35 if you already have some random parts lying around.

Comment: Thanks browly. While good reliable and accurate information is easilly available for Raspberry devices, there's much more hype when it comes to PC specs. And as I said, I do want a windows box, mainly for compatibility with existing products and software. I probably couldn't, for example, get a Netflix player for the Raspberry.

Comment: Windows is expensive. Do you have your own licence already?

Comment: @NZKshatriya In his comment to sawreal's answer, he clarified that he wants an off-the-shelf WIndows box, so not a build request.

Comment: I think you're using the terms "PC" and "WIndows" interchangeably, but they are not the same thing. You may want to change "PC" to "Windows" in each instance to clarify what you want. Linux boxes and even Macs are [technically PCs now](http://www.howtogeek.com/195224/macs-are-pcs-can-we-stop-pretending-they-arent/).

Comment: @browly - Yes thats a good point, though I wouldn't be terribly opposed to a Linux box, and I did find it amusing when Apple started building Dell based Macs :-). But wouldn't you agree that within reason, the minimum technical specifications required to perform the tasks of interest should, by now, be independent of the OS? See, I'm not looking for a specific product recommendation, but the truth about the specs needed. For all I know, I may already have dusty 12 year old machines around here running win-XP, that might be fully capable of what i want to do given the right video card.

Comment: @Alpha3031 - yes... I have what are called "site" licences to install windows on additional machines, at least up to Win-7, if in fact something I bought did not already have an adequate OEM version installed.

Comment: I also wish to comment that, I am having a very hard time conveying what I'm actually asking here. Its probably me not articulating well, but I'm doing my best. I am asking for hardware specifications to be reasonably sure they will do the tasks I described. I realize some operating systems do better jobs at different tasks, and some take better advantage of certain newer CPU features. But I'm hoping to learn what specs will put me in the "safe" zone, without overpaying for 20 times the capability than I actually need. CPU speed, cores, FSB speed, video card specs... those kinds of things.

Comment: @browly  OP still needs to post what his overall budget is, as well as other requirements he is looking for, else this is too broad *should have voted as subject is too  broad*

Comment: PC = Personal Computer = MAC/Linux/Windows.....the era of MAC vs IBM/PC is long dead.  That said, [here is a search](http://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductList.aspx?Submit=ENE&N=100019096%204814%208000&IsNodeId=1&bop=And&order=BESTMATCH&LeftPriceRange=0%20500) on newegg for systems up to the $500 price point, as a budget has not been specified.

Comment: @browly Would it have been better if the title said "minimum specifications" rather than "minimum cost"? You see, this goes back to my frustration expressed in my last comment. Maybe "up to $500" IS a specification in some sense, but its not at all what I'm asking. If I have specs I can look for, who knows what "low cost" system I might be able to use.

Comment: Probably. I think what you're really asking is "How can I tell if a computer can play Full HD video or not", and the answer seems to be, "Virtually all out-of-the-box systems on the market today can play Full HD video." This means determining the minimum requirements for Full HD video isn't particularly useful. This site is geared more towards addressing specific, practical issues, and listing the requirements for various system functions leans theoretical.

Comment: @Browly well, again i appreciate the input, but I disagree with your answer. First of all, I never said I wanted to buy a NEW system, and did say I was on a budget. That means possibly using an older system. Knowing HOW old I can go requires knowing what SPECs to look for. But since you believe my desire for understanding true numerical specifications for a task is "too theoretical" for a "hardware recommendation" board, you're free to ask the moderator to remove it. 

Seems many people who are NOT able to answer questions are very quick to want them removed, or an easier question asked.

Comment: @Randy  Most video cards on the market these days are capable of 1080p output, and as long as you have a motherboard and a power supply that meet said cards requirements, you can install into a system and have 1080p output.   That said, please read the following:  [What is a high quality question?](http://meta.hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/205/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-be-high-quality).

Comment: @Randy  Although I prefer people do their own basic research....here is another [newegg search](http://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductList.aspx?Submit=Property&N=100007709%2050001402%2050001312%2050001315%2050001561%2050001314%2050001669%2050001419%2050012150%2050001471%20600007541%20600335272%20600335568%20600335271%20600528884%20600007610%20600007600%20600560925%204814%20600083901%20601186533%20600528839%208000%204025%20600486270&IsNodeId=1&bop=And&order=BESTMATCH)  specifying budget video cards, $25-$50 range, max res of 4096x2160.    Lowest price $32.99, highest $44.99

Comment: @NZKshatriya with all due respect, judging a quality question requires reading the question and at least understanding what is being asked. Yes I think discovering whether a video card can support hi def resolution is very easy and basic. As i mentioned, even my 1990s Dell Laptop can support  that resolution. What it can't do is manage more than a few FPS when displaying full screen video at that resolution. Why? Because it lacks some critical specs related to processing power and system speed. So far no one is offering numbers that would. If no one knows it doesn't make the question bad.

Comment: Oh i read your question:  First you ask for a broad answer of "what critical specs and hardware (CPU type, clock speed, FSB speeds, number of cores, OS, Video card) I will need to accomplish one simple thing: Be able to live stream videos, play DVDs, and play various downloaded video/movie files, while driving my TV to its full 1920 x 1080 resolution"  Which is not in line with this site as per how to ask a quality question.  Then in comments you point out other things.

Comment: @Randy It might not be that your 1900 Dell needs more processing power, it could be that you need different software. Have you looked into video players that support the hardware decoder on your graphics card? If you get videos encoded with a codec supported by your graphics card, and use the right video player, you don't need much CPU power.

Comment: @Browly The Dell I spoke of, that does have a 1920 x 1080 output, was a Dell Latitude D600. It has no option for changing video hardware. But just playing a DVD  (PowerDVD software), or a simple FLASH or Netflix stream, and it struggles to display even a few FPS. Consider: 24 bit color, at 1920 x 1080 pixels, at 30 FPS requires 186 megabytes per second to be moved to screen memory. That's just MOVING it! Add the CPU overhead to decompress a stream from ANY kind of player, and its clear that the bus and CPU speeds in that old laptop could not keep up.

Comment: **Public Service Notice:** This comment thread has got rather long; can I suggest rolling any pertinent details into the question, and taking any remaining discussion or conversation to chat?

Comment: Edited and reworded to the best of my ability. As its still considered too broad for here, I'll discuss this in a different forum. If you wish I'll delete. Whatever the moderators think.

Answer (score -1):

You can't go wrong with an Orange Pi board.

The Orange Pi One board costs $9 and with standard shipping, $14. It can capture and play video in 1080 @ 30fps.

https://www.aliexpress.com/store/product/Orange-Pi-One-ubuntu-linux-and-android-mini-PC-Beyond-and-Compatible-with-Raspberry-Pi-2/1553371_32603308880.html?spm=2114.12010608.0.0.3icumZ

Or go with the new Orange Pi PC 2. Which has full support for 4K video. It costs about $23 with standard shipping.

https://www.aliexpress.com/store/product/New-Orange-Pi-PC-2-H5-64bit-Support-the-Lubuntu-linux-and-android-mini-PC-Beyond/1553371_32761481418.html?spm=2114.12010608.0.0.3icumZ

I believe the first board I posted also supports 4K but I'm not sure how quickly it would playback.

Comment: Thanks, but for now, and to avoid making an overly time consuming project out of this, I'm likely going to stick with  off the shelf windows box (anvy version) PC and video card, and I'm mainly trying to learn what critical specs I need to look for to play hi-def video. I don't want something where the wife will have to call me anytime she wants to operate it. But I must admit that for a future project, that Orange Pi looks pretty impressive for the price.

Comment: @Randy I think it would be hard to find an off-the-shelf Windows box that _doesn't_ play full HD video. The fact that the tiny Raspberry Pi has no trouble shows how easy it is. Did you look at the [HP Stream](https://smile.amazon.com/HP-Stream-11-y010nr-Celeron-Personal/dp/B01JLCKP48)? About $200 new. [Micro desktops](https://smile.amazon.com/Peformance-Dell-Inspiron-Desktop-Celeron/dp/B018ON5ILU) are even cheaper.

Comment: @Randy It really is. The Retrorangepi has a new image coming out pretty soon, and if you add Kodi to the mix its as simple as plugging in a game controller to control the box, your wife likely won't have to configure any of the settings as long as it is all setup to that point, all she would have to do is turn it on and navigate to Kodi with a few button presses. But yes, you can find tons of windows computers that can handle it. I've got a laptop from 2008 with 4gb of ram and it still handles everything in this day and age great.

Comment: @browly so there really must be no difference between that micro desktop and an x86 development board. Aside from the nice little case and pre-loaded OS.